# Нужно ли ставить тире?

Tags: пунктуация

"Планирую какую-то себе приобрести - рассматриваю по сайтам."

Answer (score 1):

Тере - это здрасте по эстонски. Ставят [тИре](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/rules/158-tire). В данном случае - вполне можно, другой вариант - закончите предложение (поставьте точку) и начните новое. Или поставьте запятую вместо точки , и получится сложносочинённое предложение.

Answer (score 0):

Это сложное бессоюзное предложение, второе простое предложение имееет значение следствия, поэтому ставится ТИРЕ. Ср.*:Планирую какую-то себе приобрести, так что  рассматриваю [что?] на  сайтах.*